# Create another branch on existing branch

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a scenario like this :

- On remote we have DEV branch
- On local i have 1 branch name #feature1

After push #feature1 to remote, now i want to work on new feature #feature2.
But i want changes in #feature1 to continue with #feature2

What should be the next action :

- Checkout new branch #feature2 on #feature1. If i take this action, is that mean when i create a PR #feature2 will be merged in #feature1 (not sure about that)
- Checkout #feature2 on local Dev branch and merge #feature1 to #feature2 then continue.

Need help to clarify this. Thanks guy !

Comment: “But i want changes in #feature1 to continue with #feature2” But feature 1 has not been approved. So you are violating the whole purpose of pull requests.

Comment: Yea, thats the problem. Our reviewer may be the blockpoint, he just not have enough time to review with all those changes from members. But we have to continue with the Sprint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i want changes in #feature1 to continue with #feature2

1. If you create Pull request and merger the branch #feature1 to branch
   dev, you can Sync the local and remote code, then create branch
   #feature based on branch dev.
2. If the branch do not merger, and you want to get branch #feature 1 code in the new branch #feature 2, you could checkout new branch #feature2
   on #feature1.

> is that mean when i create a PR #feature2 will be merged in #feature1 (not sure about that)

No, you could still create a PR to merge branch #feature2 to dev or other branches.

In addition, If you use Scenario 2, you need to be aware of code conflicts.

Comment: Thanks, i may try this option and see if the it could be merged into dev br

Comment: Hi @hoangnh, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi Vito, just pushed up and created an PR, and I think it worked well as expected. Used solution 2. Thank you again Vito

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to checkout #2 from origin (master or dev)

If the new branch is created, you can merge #1 into #2. If you are in #2:
`git merge #1`

I also recommend to update working branches reqularely with its origin (master or dev) to avoid large diffs when merging this working branch back.

Comment: Yea, that could be good, but problem is when i check file changes in my PR (#2 pushed). There're also files that changes in #1 (#1 not merge into master/dev in remote origin)

Comment: This is a regular problem when there are dependencies between 2 working branches.
I have two ideas:
- stop working on #2 until #1 is ready.
- regulary merge #1 into #2.
I think its not a good idea to merge #2 back until PR for #1 is accepted. As I understood, #2 relates on #1, so it can't be merged back before #1 is merged because it contains #1!